# Issue with my sas code using array. Outcome is not as expected

Tags: sas

I have been trying to execute a sas code using arrays. Strangely, it is not working the way i was expecting. So i used another approach and code runs fine with second method. But still i want to know ehat is wrong with the first method. Following is my code:

```
data have;
input free_m prevention substitution oth;
datalines;
. . . .
. 0 0 0
1 1 0 0
;
run;

data test;
set have;
/*method1*/
array a1(*) prevention substitution oth;
do i=1 to dim(a1);
    if free_m=. and prevention=0 and substitution=0 and oth=0 then a1(i)=.;
end;

/*method2*/
/*
if free_m=. and prevention=0 and substitution=0 and oth=0 then 
do;
    prevention=.;
    substitution=.;
    oth=.;
end;
*/
drop i;
run;

proc sql;
select * from test;
quit;
```

The outcome with /*method2*/ is correct and it is what i want:

[image]

But with /*method1*/, i am getting following output:

[image]

Is there anything wrong in method1? Kindly help!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cutting off the limb that you are sitting on.

The first method works fine for I=1 and I=2 but when you get to I=3 and I=4 the values of `prevention` has been change from `0` to missing by the earlier iterations of the do loop.  `prevention` and `a1(2)` refer to the same thing.